# CSS inside user control changing its path in aspx

Tags: html, css, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control where I have called an external CSS file using relative path. User control has banner strip with some link buttons for which I have applied styles using CSS classes. I use this user control in aspx pages which are located in some other folder. When the aspx page is rendered, the path in the user control getting changed dynamically.So the styles are not getting applied to banner strip said above.

For example my CSS file is located in `D:\home\development\compages\css\banner.css`, 
ascx user control in `d:\home\development\compages\sec\usercontrol1.ascx`, aspx page in `d:\home\development\compages\sec\10011\splash.aspx`

css link in user control: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ctis.css">`

When I register the user control in aspx, the rendered html is searching the css in compages\sec\css\banner.css, instead of picking it from compages\css\banner.css

How to overcome this path issue?